# How should I change the resources of the Main NavigationView so that it doesn't affect any other NavigationView present inside the Main NavigationView

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I have a situation where I'm using a NavigationView(SubNavigationView) inside another NavigtionView(MainNavigationView).I have altered some of the resources of the MainNavigtionView but I don't want these changes to be reflected in the SubNavigationView.

As a temporary fix I have given resources separately for both NavigationViews.

```
    <NavigationView>
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="item 1">
            </NavigationViewItem>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Top">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="item 2">
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="item 3">
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            
            <NavigationView.Resources>
                <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemAccentColorDark3" />
            </NavigationView.Resources>
            
        </NavigationView>
        
        <NavigationView.Resources>
            <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemAccentColor" />
        </NavigationView.Resources>
        
    </NavigationView>
```